# Problem regarding Epsilon-Delta definition of limits

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I came across this problem in "Introduction to Real Analysis" by Bartle and had a doubt regarding the solution to a given problem.
I needed to determine a condition on $|x-1|$ that will ensure that 
$$|(x^2-1)| < 1/2 $$

I started out by factorising : $|x^2-1| = |(x-1)(x+1)| <1/2 $

We have control over $|x-1|$ however we need to get rid of the $|x+1|$ factor to get a relation very similar to $|x-1| <\delta$.

This is where I am having a problem. In the examples given, they have generally assumed that $|x-1|<1$. By presupposing this condition, I am able to solve it but am not able to understand why 1 is being chosen since it seems like an arbitrary choice and the method should also work for some other value of $\delta$. This does not seem to be the case as if you take any other number, you do not get the correct condition. Could someone please explain the rational behind using only 1? Thank You.

Comment: Such $\epsilon, \delta$ questions do not have a unique answer. Your $\delta$ may be different from your peer's and both answers may be correct.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Alright thank you because this is usually what I have struggled in Epsilon-Delta proofs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People usually choose $1$ because that's the simplest choice. But any number greater than $0$ will do. I will do it with $4$. So, let us start by assuming that $\lvert x-1\rvert<4$. Then\begin{align}\lvert x+1\rvert&=\bigl\lvert(x-1)+2\bigr\rvert\\&\leqslant\lvert x-1\rvert+2\\&<6.\end{align}So, for any $\varepsilon>0$, take $\delta=\min\left\{4,\frac\varepsilon6\right\}$, and then\begin{align}\lvert x-1\rvert<\delta\implies\lvert x^2-1\rvert&=\lvert x-1\rvert\times\lvert x+1\rvert\\&<\frac\varepsilon6\times6\\&=\varepsilon.\end{align}

Comment: Does this imply that the approach is equally valid for any value of $\delta$? Also, if we consider $\delta$ to be less than 1, we get a wider range for the values of |x-1| while if $\delta$ is greater than 1 then the range is limited.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The number $\delta$ is not *any* number. In my approach, it belongs to $\left(0,\min\left\{4,\frac\varepsilon6\right\}\right)$.

Comment: Sorry I meant to ask if it is alright to consider \

Comment: And what does *that* mean?

Comment: Sorry I meant to ask if it is alright to consider 0<|x-1|<1 because for such values, we get an extended range. For eg: if |x-1|<1/2, then we get |x+1|<5/2 which will imply that |x-1|<$\epsilon$/5. Therefore we get $\delta$ belongs to (0, min{1/2,$\epsilon$/5}).

Comment: Yes, it is correct to take $1$. It is correct to take any number greater than $0$.

Comment: @AdityaSriram: it is not necessary to find all values of $x$ which satisfy $|x^2-1|<1/2$. What is desired here is find a $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x-1|<\delta\implies |x^2-1|<1/2$. If one $\delta$ works any smaller value of $\delta$ also works. And we need not find the largest $\delta$ to get largest possible range of values of $x$.